# Public datasets for Text summarization

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, medical, research, text

I'm looking for raw text datasets in HealthCare domain (scientific journals, articles, etc..) for Text summarization.
Where can I get such data (publicly distributed)?

Comment: Hi could you share link of pubMed 1M dataset ?
I am unable to locate it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/8473)

Answer (score 2):

I have used both [PubMed](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/pubmed) and [Clinical Trials](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/resources/download) datasets for this.  The pubmed is by far the larger set of content with over 1M journals.